# Installing custom CoreMLTools

Tags: artificial-intelligence, caffe, coreml, coremltools

When converting a Caffe Model with [CoreMLTools](https://github.com/apple/coremltools) I found a Layer limitation that I'm trying to fix on my own fork of the project.

I've successfully ran:

`cmake .
make`

My problem now is how would I use this version I built in the normal workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the caffe subtree under coremltools/deps/caffe/ with your own adjusted caffe (Or merge the original CoreML caffe subtree with your changes).